# Pandas: missing value imputation

Tags: python, performance, pandas

## I want to find a more efficient solution to the following problem:

My dataset is about online games. Each player may have multiple plays (rows in the df). Each play has its corresponding timestamp. However, some events are lacking their id (session identifier). 
I need an efficient method to fill the NaN of the id columns, using information from the other two columns.

This is the dataset:

```
d = {'player': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4'],
        'date': ['2018-01-01 00:17:01', '2018-01-01 00:17:05','2018-01-01 00:19:05', '2018-01-01 00:21:07', '2018-01-01 00:22:09', 
                 '2018-01-01 00:22:17', '2018-01-01 00:25:09', '2018-01-01 00:25:11', '2018-01-01 00:27:28', '2018-01-01 00:29:29',
                  '2018-01-01 00:30:35',  '2018-02-01 00:31:16', '2018-02-01 00:35:22', '2018-02-01 00:38:16', 
                 '2018-02-01 00:38:20', '2018-02-01 00:55:15', '2018-01-03 00:55:22', '2018-01-03 00:58:16', 
                 '2018-01-03 00:58:21', '2018-03-01 01:00:35', '2018-03-01 01:20:16', '2018-03-01 01:31:16', '2018-03-01 02:44:21'], 
        'id': [np.nan, np.nan, 'a', 'a', 'b', np.nan, 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', np.nan, 'f', 'f', 
               'g', np.nan, 'f', 'g', 'h']}

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

  player      date          id
0   1   2018-01-01 00:17:01 NaN
1   1   2018-01-01 00:17:05 NaN
2   1   2018-01-01 00:19:05 a
3   1   2018-01-01 00:21:07 a
4   1   2018-01-01 00:22:09 b
5   1   2018-01-01 00:22:17 NaN
6   1   2018-01-01 00:25:09 b
7   1   2018-01-01 00:25:11 c
8   1   2018-01-01 00:27:28 c
9   1   2018-01-01 00:29:29 c
10  1   2018-01-01 00:30:35 c
11  2   2018-02-01 00:31:16 d
12  2   2018-02-01 00:35:22 d
13  2   2018-02-01 00:38:16 e
14  2   2018-02-01 00:38:20 e
15  2   2018-02-01 00:55:15 NaN
16  3   2018-01-03 00:55:22 f
17  3   2018-01-03 00:58:16 f
18  3   2018-01-03 00:58:21 g
19  3   2018-03-01 01:00:35 NaN
20  3   2018-03-01 01:20:16 f
21  3   2018-03-01 01:31:16 g
22  4   2018-03-01 02:44:21 h
```

## This was my line of reasoning:

### **1. Groupby player and id**

computing the first and last date for each play.

```
my_agg = df.groupby(['player', 'id']).date.agg([min, max])
my_agg

                       min           max
 player id      
    1    a  2018-01-01 00:19:05  2018-01-01 00:21:07
         b  2018-01-01 00:22:09  2018-01-01 00:25:09
         c  2018-01-01 00:25:11  2018-01-01 00:30:35
    2    d  2018-02-01 00:31:16  2018-02-01 00:35:22
         e  2018-02-01 00:38:16  2018-02-01 00:38:20
    3    f  2018-01-03 00:55:22  2018-03-01 01:20:16
         g  2018-01-03 00:58:21  2018-03-01 01:31:16
    4    h  2018-03-01 02:44:21  2018-03-01 02:44:21
```

### **2. Create a function**

that compares the timestamp of the play to every id available, and see whether or not it falls within range. Basically, if it falls within range of a single session of play id, I want to fill the NaN with the id label. If it is not within range of any session id, I want to fill the NaN with 0. If it is within range of multiple sessions (theoretically it should not be), it fills the missing value with -99.

```
#define a function to sort the missing values 
def check_function(time):
    #compare every date event with the range of the sessions. 
    current_sessions = group.loc[(group['min']<time) & (group['max']>time)]
    #store length, that is the number of matches. 
    count = len(current_sessions)
    #How many matches are there for any missing id value?
    # if 0 the event lies outside all the possible ranges
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    #if >1, it is impossible to say to which session the event belongs
    if count > 1:
        return -99
    #in this case the event belongs clearly to just one session
    return current_sessions.index[0][1]
```

### **3. Apply the function player by player**

And store the results to create a new dataframe, with the desired output.

```
grouped = my_agg.groupby(level=0)

final = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in grouped:
    mv_per_player = df.loc[df['player'] == name]    
    mv_per_player.loc[mv_per_player.id.isnull(),'id'] = mv_per_player.loc[mv_per_player.id.isnull(),'date'].apply(check_function)
    final = final.append(mv_per_player)

final

  player         date       id
0   1   2018-01-01 00:17:01 0
1   1   2018-01-01 00:17:05 0
2   1   2018-01-01 00:19:05 a
3   1   2018-01-01 00:21:07 a
4   1   2018-01-01 00:22:09 b
5   1   2018-01-01 00:22:17 b
6   1   2018-01-01 00:25:09 b
7   1   2018-01-01 00:25:11 c
8   1   2018-01-01 00:27:28 c
9   1   2018-01-01 00:29:29 c
10  1   2018-01-01 00:30:35 c
11  2   2018-02-01 00:31:16 d
12  2   2018-02-01 00:35:22 d
13  2   2018-02-01 00:38:16 e
14  2   2018-02-01 00:38:20 e
15  2   2018-02-01 00:55:15 0
16  3   2018-01-03 00:55:22 f
17  3   2018-01-03 00:58:16 f
18  3   2018-01-03 00:58:21 g
19  3   2018-03-01 01:00:35 -99
20  3   2018-03-01 01:20:16 f
21  3   2018-03-01 01:31:16 g
22  4   2018-03-01 02:44:21 h
```

## Conclusion

This process works, but is there a way to make the process more efficient and faster? I think the bottleneck is  the for loop, but I cannot find an alternative solution.